# Android - rooted user - mount: Read-only file system

Tags: android, system, root, tablet, android-permissions

Someone can help me? I have the root but can not modify rw:

```
root@android:/# mount -o rw, remount /dev/block/system
mount: Read-only file system
```

while from adb:

```
C:\androidSDK\sdk\platform-tools\adb remount
remount succeeded
```

If then I try to open a file inside /system is read only. I have a 'irulu ax105' tablet. This is my current situation:

```
C:\androidSDK\sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
root@android:/ # ls -l
ls -l
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2000-01-02 19:46 acct
drwxrwx--- system   cache             2014-04-16 23:00 cache
dr-x------ root     root              2000-01-02 19:46 config
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2000-01-02 19:46 d -> /sys/kernel/debug
drwxrwx--x system   system            2000-01-02 18:49 data
-rw-r--r-- 400      401           116 2013-12-13 03:19 default.prop
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2000-01-02 19:46 dev
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2000-01-02 19:46 etc -> /system/etc
-rwxr-x--- 400      401        113752 2013-12-13 03:19 init
-rwxr-x--- 400      401          2487 2013-12-13 03:19 init.goldfish.rc
-rwxr-x--- 400      401         20247 2013-12-13 03:19 init.rc
-rwxr-x--- 400      401          5805 2013-12-13 03:22 init.sun7i.rc
-rwxr-x--- 400      401          3445 2013-12-13 03:19 init.sun7i.usb.rc
-rwxr-x--- 400      401          1795 2013-12-13 03:19 init.trace.rc
-rwxr-x--- 400      401          3915 2013-12-13 03:19 init.usb.rc
-rwxr-x--- 400      401       2457600 2013-12-13 03:19 initlogo.rle
drwxrwxr-x root     system            2000-01-02 19:46 mnt
-rw-r--r-- 400      401        649354 2013-12-13 03:19 nand.ko
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              1969-12-31 18:00 proc
drwx------ root     root              2013-11-19 04:20 root
drwxr-x--- 400      401               2013-12-13 03:19 sbin
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2000-01-02 19:46 sdcard -> /mnt/sdcard
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2000-01-02 19:46 sys
drwxr-xr-x root     root              1969-12-31 18:00 system
-rw-r--r-- 400      401           272 2013-12-13 03:19 ueventd.goldfish.rc
-rw-r--r-- 400      401          4024 2013-12-13 03:19 ueventd.rc
-rw-r--r-- 400      401          1346 2013-12-13 03:19 ueventd.sun7i.rc
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2000-01-02 19:46 vendor -> /system/vendor
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You shouldn't have a space after the comma in your options to mount.

Comment: thanks but the problem is not solved

Comment: Use the mount point, not the raw device.  Like this: `mount -o rw,remount /system`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works for me

```
mount -o rw,remount rootfs /
```

or to remount `/system`

```
mount -o rw,remount /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /system
```

Comment: **+1,** The first one worked for writing on *`/`*, I actually didn't realise that remounting `/system` as rw doesn't affect root itself.